# Subcaption error

Tags: texstudio, subcaption

Im using TexStudio 2.12.22. When trying to make subfigures I get the following error:

> ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
>
> ! Missing number, treated as zero.
>
> to be read again>
>                          *
>   l.157      \begin{subfigure}{0.5*\textwidth}"

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5*\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5*\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

UPDATE
Thanks to Leandris, the * was messing it up. replaced with {0.5\textwidth}

Comment: Tried it with 0.2 and 0.01 but still get the same error. I also get:! Missing number, treated as zero.

Comment: Remove the `*`. `\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}` should work but will result in an overfull box warning.

Comment: Thanks it was the * that was messing things up.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `*`. `\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}` instead of `\begin{subfigure}{0.5*\textwidth}` works perfectly fine.

Placing two subfigures next to each other that both take up half the textwidth will result in an overfull box warning as there will be a small white spce between them. This can be overcome when removing the `\hfill` and when placing a `%`sign at the end of the first `subfigure` environment. Alternatively you could also decrease the width of both subfigures.

[image]

(Red lines indicate the start of the margins.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{subfigure}%
%    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```